# Can't get link_to_unless_current to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

After someone pointed `link_to_unless_current` out to me, I would like to apply it to my dashboard sidebar. However, I can't get it to work, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

This is my current sidebar

```
.dashboard_bar
  %ul
    = link_to admin_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-dashboard
    = link_to admin_cs_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-heart
    = link_to admin_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-money
    = link_to admin_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-group
    = link_to admin_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-bug
    = link_to admin_dashboard_path do
      %li.icon-hdd
```

When I change `link_to` to `link_to_unless_current`, it just screws up my css and the icons are no longer clickable.

Can someone enlighten me on how to fix it?

P.S. I did check out the [Rails guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) on this, but still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You should provide to each `link_to_unless_current` controller and action where this link would be working. Did you?

Comment: No, I didn't set up any actions. I'm relatively new to Rails (and Ruby), so I thought I could just replace link_to with link_to_unless_current. Guess I'll do some more studying!

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that your are on the same url as admin_dashboard_path. So, all your links are disabled and shown as text.

Comment: I made sure I wasn't, but just for testing purposes, I changed the other links to "#". Going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after sitting down with someone who knows more about Rails, we came to the following solution:

```
.dashboard_bar
  %ul
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', admin_dashboard_path, :class => "icon-dashboard" do
        %span.icon-dashboard
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', admin_cs_dashboard_path, :class => "icon-heart" do
        %span.icon-heart
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', "#", :class => "icon-money" do
        %span.icon-money
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', "#", :class => "icon-group" do
        %span.icon-group
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', "#", :class => "icon-bug" do
        %span.icon-bug
    %li
      = link_to_unless_current '', "#", :class => "icon-hdd" do
        %span.icon-hdd
```

The main problem was that the links were around the `li`, while they should be inside the `li`. With applying the class to the link with `:class => "icon-*"` and to the `span`, we managed to create the look and functionality I was looking for.

As soon as `link_to_unless_current` sees that I'm on the current page of that link, it changes the link to a span, creating possibilities to use css on the icons for both the current page and the other links.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a block to `#link_to_unless_current` does not behaves as passing a block to `#link_to` : the content of block is used [as an alternative content if link is indeed current path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current).

So, when you write :

```
= link_to admin_dashboard_path do
  %li.icon-money
```

What you actually say is : make a link to admin_dashboard_path with nil name. But if it's the current path, write `<li class="icon-money">` instead.

If you want to achieve what you wanted (the list item inside link), you should go something like that rather :

```
= link_to_unless_current '<li class="icon-money"></li>'.html_safe, admin_dashboard_path
```

This being quite odd in a haml file, the best solution is probably to keep your links *inside* your list items.